# How to convert Json to Java Object using Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

Does anyone can help me to find a solution?

im using Jersey to create REST web services, i built a web service and expose it, so can create a new user in a data base.
I also created the client, and it sends me the next json, in a POST using de Gson Library:

```
    {
        "name":"myname",
        "userID":"12345",
        "password":"sha1passwordASDESFSGSD",
        "active":"1",
        "profile":"2",
        "job":"Manager"
        }
```

After the client send me the Json i recive it in my REST method. I can also converted into a string and print it.
But if i try to converted to a object, nothing happens

Im using the Gson library to make the job to convert the Json into a object. I put some tryCatch but the debuger jumps that lines of code and doesnt print anything.

```
 @POST
  @Path("user/in/")
  @Produces("application/json")
  public String InsertUser(InputStream inStr)
  { 

      String line=null, res = "POST 200 > ";
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStr));
      try {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
              {             
                    System.out.println(line);
                    res += line;
              }


          }catch (IOException e){ 
              e.printStackTrace(); 
              }
      try{

          User user = new Gson().fromJson(line, User.class);  
          System.out.println(user.getName());

      }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("Error al convertir jo object " + e.getCause()  + e.getMessage());
      }

      return "POST 200 > " ;
  }
```

And my class User (the class also has the set and get methods)

```
public class User {

private String name;
private String userID;
private String password;
private String active;
private String profile;
private String job;
}
// Methods removed for brevity
```

Comment: What are you doing about the `userInformation`?

Comment: What you mean? is the object but in the Json String, i dont see your point

Comment: the problem is very obvious, your user class must have a field called userInformation, which should be of another type, containing fields from your user class.

Comment: Your code is only deserializing the last line.

Comment: See the duplicate.

Comment: So, i need to create a userInformation Class? and that class needs to have the user Class inside?

Comment: That would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @mavi or better, change your json to only have the inner part, and use your existing user class

Comment: @AshkanKzme Thanks, i already do it, my new json is ('{ "name":"david","userID":"1234","password":"sha1passwordASDESFSGSD","active":"1","profile":"2","job":"Manager"}')
But it doesnt work, the debugger jump the line 'UserInformation user = new Gson().fromJson(line, UserInformation.class);' maybe the problem is in the var line

Comment: I change my code a little bit, im not using String line, instead im using a InputStreamREader ' InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inStr);
     
     UserInformation user = new Gson().fromJson(isr, UserInformation.class);'


But it doent work, does anyone know why??????????????????????????????????????????????????????